# How to maximise stomach drop when driving through a dip

Tags: forces, home-experiment

I have a couple of young kids, and on our school commute each morning we drive through a dip in the road. The dip is probably about 5 meters deep (15 feet) and the speed limit in the area is 60 km/h (40 m/h). We find it great fun to pretend its a dip on a rollercoaster, and I've been trying to work out the most efficient pattern of accelerating / decelerating through the dip to maximise the "stomach-drop" effect. But I'd like to get science on my side!

How do I maximise the stomach-drop? When should I be accelerating, coasting or braking?

[image: Annotated graph of dip in road]

*Above are some sample segments of the dip, if the recommended accelerating/coasting/braking phases do not match up please specify better segments*

Right now my hunch is to accelerate to point B (as the dip starts), then coast / brake through to point C, then accelerate again to point E, then coast again. But if I can eke out even more stomach drop, I cannot wait to test it out on my kids!

Comment: It's something you could test with a Hotwheels track with your kids.  I'd think you'd want to go as slow as possible from A to B to minimize horizontal travel at B.  Then step on the gas just beyond B to accelerate down the slope to maximize vertical travel speed.  Then coast from C to D.  Then step on the gas again at D to maximize speed of upwards vertical travel.  Think of a roller coaster that climbs very slowly to the top of the hill, then drops very quickly and rises up the next hill very quickly.

Comment: Max stomach drop is achieved when you're weightless (i.e., when all four wheels leave the ground.) My guess is, you'd be happier if the launch point was somewhere around E, and the landing somewhere beyond F.  Maybe not so happy if you launch at B and land anywhere between D and E. It all kind of depends on how much road is between C and D.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I really try hard to keep all 4 wheels on the ground at all times! It is a busy commuter road and I doubt my wife would be happy with me ramping our SUV, even if it is in the name of science!

Comment: @foolishmuse isn't the slow climb rollercoasters do at the beginning of a circuit all about building up anticipation? At such slow speeds, there isn't much additional force on ones "stomach" than just gravity pulling straight down. I think the ideal answer here is going to be a mix of maximising "negative forces" during the B-C portion and then again maximising the "positive forces" during the "D-E" to get the largest possible "apparent drop".

Comment: @mccdyl001  My thought is that a fast speed from A to B would tend to launch the car horizontally at point B, resulting in more of a sloped drop down to the bottom,  but what we want is maximum vertical drop.  So slow speed to B, then accelerate as fast as possible down the slope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After giving this way too much thought..**

I believe a solution of the problem would be as follows. Consider a slightly updated "dip-chart":

[image: Updated Dip Chart]

Assuming constant acceleration going forwards, at points A, C & E the force acting on our stomach would just be gravity pulling it downwards at 9.8m/s:

[image: Stomach at rest]

As we start going into the dip (point A), the car starts getting an additional downward acceleration. Our stomach, being a bag of liquid suspended inside our body, is similar to a mass held in place by a pair of springs. As the car accelerates downwards, the stomach lifts "up". The maximum amount of "upward" lift is at point B:

[image: Stomach at max downward acceleration point]

As we continue on the curve toward point C, the downward acceleration of the car tapers off and we reach point C and our original balanced stomach:

[image: Stomach at rest]

Now as we climb up out of the dip, the acceleration of the car gains an upward direction too, and so the "slow to react" stomach is pulled downwards on its springs, reaching its maximum at point D:

[image: Stomach at max upward acceleration point]

Finally, we exit the dip at point E and once again have a resting stomach:

[image: Stomach at rest]

**Now for maximizing the "stomach drop feeling"** (via acceleration / coasting / braking)

If we acceleration between point A & point B, we add an additional sideways force onto our stomach spring. So not only does it "move upward", it will always move "backward" a little:

[image: Stomach at max upwards/backwards position]

We then coast / maintain speed from point B to point C, and then from point C to point D we decelerate / brake to make our stomach get a horizontal forward movement:

[image: Stomach at maximum forward/downward position]

That gives a final set of instructions as follows:

- Up to point A, maintain constant speed
- Point A -> B, accelerate
- Point B -> C, maintain constant speed
- Point C -> D, decelerate
- Point D -> onwards, accelerate back up to speed

Comment: After several very successful runs using this technique I can say the kids find it brilliantly fun and my wife swears the next time she's throwing up. Give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

The "stomach drop" you are referring to is due to the centripetal force provided by the curved road. The maximum effect will be felt at the bottom most point of the dip.

The force during the dip will be $mg$ plus a component of ${1\over 2}mv^2$. Hence to maximize force experienced, you can crank up mass and/or velocity of the vehicle.

My suggestion is that you accelerate from the start till the bottom most point (so as to have the maximum possible velocity) and then ease up towards the end. If possible you can take a bigger car or more people to increase the mass too!

Comment: Would coasting between B & C not give a bit of "negative" stomach drop (as the car drops away below you), so that when you then accelerate from point C to the bottom point the apparent difference is larger than just straight forward acceleration?